# How to store/save the output from a command in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, command

I want to save a command output to an variable in a bash script. I've tried possibilities that I've found here in this forum but it doesn't work for my script.

I use the command: `cangen vcan0 -g 4 -I 7E -L 8 -D r -v` to generate CAN data. -g, -I, -L, -D, -V are parameter to define how the CAN data have to be generate.

Normally i get the data printed on the Terminal like this:

[image: cangen output on bash]

I want to store this output in a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

#We have to generate a virtual CAN bus Interface

sudo modprobe vcan
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
sudo ip link set up vcan0

candata= `(cangen vcan0 -g 0.008 -I 7E -L 8 -D r -v)`
echo $candata
```

and when i run my script, i do not obtain the output from my cangen-command. I get the output:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

I do not have much experience with Linux and bash script programming. Can someone help me?

Comment: The error message seems to be unrelated to the construct you are asking about. Your variable already contains the output from the program `cangen` (though the parentheses are superfluous), but the error message might mean that the output is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your script works, this message is the content of $candata, and the reason for it that the vcan0 device already exists. (Have you tried several times already maybe?)

Anyhow I would suggest to write:

```
candata=$(cangen vcan0 -g 0.008 -I 7E -L 8 -D r -v)
```

or

```
candata=`cangen vcan0 -g 0.008 -I 7E -L 8 -D r -v`
```

As you have written it, you open a sub-shell which rises complexity for nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve tried it several time and i got the same message. If my script would work, I should be able to see the data. I have tried your suggestions and I always get the same message

Comment: I concurr with what tripleee commented above. I still believe that the script (as bash is concerned) is correct and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The problem was the command: sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan  This command must be run only once.